# Any way to have nice and uniform table in `moderncv` document class?

Tags: tables, moderncv, sharelatex, cv

I want to add my language skills to my resume. I used `moderncv` document class to shape my resume. And I tried to add table for those but the resulted output is not a uniform table. Is There any way to adjust my table on my preference? Thanks in advance

**reproducible code**

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Test Score}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textit{GRE}}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Verbal Reasoning} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Quantitative Reasoning}          & Analytical Writing \\ \midrule
            & xxx (xx\%) &  xxx (xx\%) & & xx (xx\%) & \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{TOEFL iBT}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
            \toprule
            Reading & Listening & Speaking & Writing \\ \midrule
            \\             xx                & xx              & xx                 & xx \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
}{}
\end{document}
```

**Expected output**

This is my expected table by using `moderncv` document class:

[image]

**UPDATE**

centering numeric figure respect to corresponding text is preferred. Also, reduce the vertical and horizontal line space and keep them geometrically aligned are expected. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using tabularx:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Test Score}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textit{GRE}}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}{YYY}
            \toprule
            Verbal  Reasoning & Quantitative Reasoning          & Analytical Writing \\ \midrule
             xxx (xx\%) &  xxx (xx\%) & xx (xx\%)  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{TOEFL iBT}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}{YYYY}
            \toprule
            Reading & Listening & Speaking & Writing \\ \midrule
            xx                & xx              & xx                 & xx \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to achieve horizontally and vertically centered contents, you could also use the following:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Test Score}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textit{GRE}}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}{XXX}
            \toprule
            Verbal Reasoning & Quantitative Reasoning          & Analytical Writing \\ \midrule
             xxx (xx\%) &  xxx (xx\%) & xx (xx\%)  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{TOEFL iBT}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}{XXXX}
            \toprule
            Reading & Listening & Speaking & Writing \\ \midrule
            xx                & xx              & xx                 & xx \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should re-define the `X` column type as  `m{#1}`.